# Is every function Lipschitz in some Riemannian metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lipschitz-functions

Let $M =\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and 
let $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.
Define the Riemannian metric 
$$
\|\delta x\|_{x} = (1+ \|\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\|)\|\delta x\|
$$ on $M$ (here $\|\cdot\|$ without a subscript means the Euclidean norm). Put the usual norm on $\mathbb{R}$. Then it seems $f$ is Lipschitz continuous since
$$
\sup_{x}\sup_{\delta x\neq 0}
\frac{
       |\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\delta x|
     }
     {
     \|\delta x\|_{x}
     }  \leq
\sup_{x}\sup_{\delta x\neq 0}
\frac{
       \|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\|\|\delta x\|
     }
     {
(1 + \|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\|)\|\delta x\|} \leq \sup_{x}\sup_{\delta x\neq 0} 1 = 1
$$
Is my thinking right on this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as far as bounding the derivative, your reasoning is correct.

However, you have to be careful regarding the *smoothness* of the metric you define. When $\nabla f(x)$ approaches $0$, then $\| \nabla f(x)\|$ ceases to be smooth in $x$. So the Riemannian metric as you have defined it, is not necessarily smooth. This can be compensated by smoothing it and being a bit more careful with the inequalities, showing that the derivative of $f$ remains bounded.

Note, however, that your proof so far has only showed that every *smooth function* is Lipschitz in some Riemannian metric. For Lischitz functions you have to add another argument, that allows you to replace your Lipschitz function with a nearby smooth function, for which you construct your Riemannian metric.